# Instagram gem: how to get next page of results?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

How do I get the next page of results using the Instagram gem?

The documentation for the API itself says there is a `pagination` hash passed in with each result (see here: http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/). How do I access that with the gem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Got it. I don't think the `pagination` hash that Instagram passes back is accessible, but you can pass in a `max_id` option when querying, to get the next set of older pictures.

```
@results = Instagram.user_recent_media(some_user_id, {access_token: token, count: 10, max_id: 197679035065553721})
```

By passing in `max_id` (the id of a photo), it will return all results older than that. So grab the id of the oldest photo from the first query, and pass it in to get the next page.

Note: when you get the results, the ids of pictures are in the form: `197679035065553721_someuserid`. You have to parse out the first bit before the underscore, and pass that in as `max_id`.

Comment: Pagination is accessible in the API response. Although the documentation doesn't mention this, when you use the Instagram gem, the hash returned contains a ``pagination`` item, in addition to the ``data`` item.

Comment: See http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ for generic information of the structure of the results. That also mentions the `pagination` attributes for endpoints that support pagination.

Comment: could any one show and example to load the next oldest set of instagram api in next page by specifying number of response per page(in php or javascript) ?

Answer (score 7):

```
Instagram.tag_recent_media(params[:q]).pagination
```

run that code and you will see the pagination attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this for a project of my own and eventually found that you can get the client to give you the pagination info by setting no_response_wrapper to true when creating the client:

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => accesstoken,
                          :no_response_wrapper => true)
```

This makes it so you can use .pagination on the response as Yigit C. Bacakoglu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You may be out of luck. If you look through the [client modules](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/tree/master/lib/instagram/client), you can see that the methods are returning the `data` field of the response, so the `pagination` field is unavailable. There's also [an issue](https://github.com/Instagram/instagram-ruby-gem/issues/25) that touches on the lack of pagination info in responses.